# Can't get a bar chart to function properly

Tags: vb.net

<del>I am in need of some help with an assignment of mine. I've been working on this for roughly a week trying to get the bars to build correctly with no luck.
Per the assignment, I have to track the spread of the flu by creating bars via .CreateGraphics. The progression of the flu is as follows:
A community of 10,000 people are exposed to the flu, in which people who have been sick for two days are immune on the third. On day 0, 200 people have been sick for 1 day and 100 have been sick for two days. With each click of the Advance one day button the data shifts so that 100 people are immune, 200 have been sick for two days and the new number of peolpe sick for one day is determined by the product of .0001735 * # of people sick the previous day * # of people susceptible the previous day.</del>

<del>However when I click the button, it appears to simply double the existing data and the image never redraws...</del>

**I have edited this post to reflect the progress I've made with the guidance of Tony Hinkle. Thank you Tony, just a few more wrinkles to iron out!**

I now am able to advance my number of susceptible people, however none of my other data shows beyond the first group of people to become immune.

Edit #2 - I've narrowed down the problem to my tempArray element values. When I assign the values in the advanceFirstDay sub they don't appear to be applied to the global array making the values of the newfirstDay and newtwoDays 0. I have verified this by adding a temporary listbox and a for loop to display the values of tempArray. The result is a NullException being thrown for tempList.Items.Add(i)

My code is below, any help you can give me / pointing out of my errors would be greatly appreciated as this is becoming increasingly frustrating...

Thank you!

```
Public Class Form1

Dim population() As Single = {97, 2, 1, 0}
Dim susceptible As Integer = population(0)
Dim firstDay As Integer = population(1)
Dim twoDays As Integer = population(2)
Dim immune As Integer = population(3)
Dim currentDay, newfirstDay, newtwoDays, newImmune, newSusceptible
Dim tempArray() = {newSusceptible, newfirstDay, newtwoDays, newImmune}
Dim advanced1Day As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub day0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles day0.Click

    'Create the graph
    Dim gr As Graphics = chart.CreateGraphics
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 475, 115) 'x-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 60, 0)  'y-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 55, 0, 65, 0) 'Tickmark
    gr.DrawString("10,000", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 0)
    gr.DrawString("Susceptible", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 90, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 1 Day", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 177, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 2 Days", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 264, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Immune", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 351, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Population * 100", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 200, 140)

    'Display the values for Day 0 of the epidemic
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 18, 30, susceptible) 'suscpetible
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 187, 113, 30, firstDay) 'sick one day
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 274, 114, 30, twoDays) 'sick two days

End Sub

Private Sub advanceDay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles advanceDay.Click

    advanceFirstDay()
    spreadIllness()

End Sub

Private Sub chart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chart.Click

End Sub

Sub spreadIllness()

    chart.Refresh()

    Dim gr As Graphics = chart.CreateGraphics
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 475, 115) 'x-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 60, 0)  'y-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 55, 0, 65, 0) 'Tickmark
    gr.DrawString("10,000", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 0)
    gr.DrawString("Susceptible", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 90, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 1 Day", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 177, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 2 Days", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 264, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Immune", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 351, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Population * 100", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 200, 140)

    'Dim newSusceptible As Integer = susceptible - firstDay - twoDays

    newImmune += newtwoDays
    newtwoDays = 0 + newfirstDay
    newSusceptible = newSusceptible - newfirstDay - newtwoDays - newImmune
    currentDay = CInt(0.0001735 * newtwoDays * newSusceptible)
    newfirstDay = currentDay

    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 114 - newSusceptible, 30, newSusceptible) 'suscpetible
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 187, 114 - newfirstDay, 30, newfirstDay) 'sick one day
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 274, 114 - newtwoDays, 30, newtwoDays) 'sick two days
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 361, 114 - newImmune, 30, newImmune) 'sick two days

End Sub

Sub advanceFirstDay()

    If advanced1Day = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    chart.Refresh()

    Dim gr As Graphics = chart.CreateGraphics
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 475, 115) 'x-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 60, 0)  'y-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 55, 0, 65, 0) 'Tickmark
    gr.DrawString("10,000", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 0)
    gr.DrawString("Susceptible", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 90, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 1 Day", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 177, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 2 Days", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 264, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Immune", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 351, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Population * 100", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 200, 140)

    'Dim newSusceptible As Integer = susceptible - firstDay - twoDays

    newImmune += twoDays
    newtwoDays = 0 + firstDay
    newSusceptible = susceptible - firstDay - newtwoDays - newImmune
    currentDay = CInt(0.0001735 * newtwoDays * newSusceptible)
    newfirstDay = currentDay


    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 114 - newSusceptible, 30, newSusceptible) 'suscpetible
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 187, 114 - newfirstDay, 30, newfirstDay) 'sick one day
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 274, 114 - newtwoDays, 30, newtwoDays) 'sick two days
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 361, 114 - newImmune, 30, newImmune) 'sick two days

    advanced1Day = True

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to manipulate graphics, or would it be OK to just modify chart series points?

Comment: I'm not sure, I was under the impression I need to use the graphics per the assignment. If it weren't for that stipulation I'd just use the chart control. How would I manipulate the series points?

Comment: The reason the values aren't progressing is that you are resetting them to the starting values every time `spreadIllness` is run.  Walk through your logic--you click the advanceDay button, which runs `spreadIllness`, and the second line of `spreadIllness` resets the values.  You have either skipped to many classes or your instructor has failed to teach some prerequisites!  You need to use global variables (declared within the class, but not in a subroutine), and then update the values of those variables in `spreadIllness`.

Comment: Also, using an array for the values makes it nice for looping to create the columns on the chart, but makes it a bit more difficult to code as then you want to assign those values to variables (such as `firstDay`) so that it is readable, but then you just have to turn around and update the array as well (which you're not doing yet).

Comment: Yes sir, I realized the mistake with my declarations after leaving the project and coming back to it, I have updated the code to reflect what I've been doing, though at this point I know it doesn't function properly yet as some of the values are incomplete and/or have not been changed yet.

Comment: I attribute a lot of the difficulty in learning this to the book we are using. Being the summer semester, the course is entirely online and email can only provide so much help, however the book covers very basic topics then asks you to program things that it fails to cover, like the above example.

Comment: To clear the chart before redrawing, use something link `gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 65, 15, 410, 100)` for the `For` loop in `spreadIllness`.  You just have to draw a rectangle the same color as the background that covers the area where the columns are drawn.

Comment: I think you understand the graphics enough to get this done--you just have to walk through the logic in fine detail for the calculations.  For example, you are calculating the new value for `currentDay` prior to assigning `twoDays` to the value of `currentDay`.  You are also never updating `susceptible`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have fixed the graph, all my data functions (or appears to) as intended. Thank you for the help Tony Hinkle!

```
Public Class Form1

Dim population() As Single = {97, 2, 1, 0}
Dim susceptible As Integer = population(0)
Dim firstDay As Integer = population(1)
Dim twoDays As Integer = population(2)
Dim immune As Integer = population(3)
Dim currentDay, newfirstDay, newtwoDays, newImmune, newSusceptible
Dim advanced1Day As Boolean = False
Dim tempArray()

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub day0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles day0.Click

    'Create the graph
    Dim gr As Graphics = chart.CreateGraphics
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 475, 115) 'x-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 60, 0)  'y-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 55, 0, 65, 0) 'Tickmark
    gr.DrawString("10,000", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 0)
    gr.DrawString("Susceptible", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 90, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 1 Day", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 177, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 2 Days", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 264, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Immune", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 351, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Population * 100", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 200, 140)

    'Display the values for Day 0 of the epidemic
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 18, 30, susceptible) 'suscpetible
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 187, 113, 30, firstDay) 'sick one day
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 274, 114, 30, twoDays) 'sick two days

End Sub

Private Sub advanceDay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles advanceDay.Click

    advanceFirstDay()
    spreadIllness()

End Sub

Private Sub chart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chart.Click

End Sub

Sub spreadIllness()

    chart.Refresh()

    Dim gr As Graphics = chart.CreateGraphics
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 475, 115) 'x-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 60, 0)  'y-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 55, 0, 65, 0) 'Tickmark
    gr.DrawString("10,000", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 0)
    gr.DrawString("Susceptible", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 90, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 1 Day", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 177, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 2 Days", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 264, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Immune", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 351, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Population * 100", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 200, 140)

    newImmune += twoDays
    newtwoDays = firstDay
    newSusceptible = susceptible - firstDay - newtwoDays - newImmune
    currentDay = CInt(0.0001735 * (newtwoDays * 100) * (newSusceptible * 100))
    newfirstDay = CInt(currentDay / 100)

    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 114 - newSusceptible, 30, newSusceptible) 'suscpetible
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 187, 114 - newfirstDay, 30, newfirstDay) 'sick one day
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 274, 114 - newtwoDays, 30, newtwoDays) 'sick two days
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 361, 114 - newImmune, 30, newImmune) 'sick two days

End Sub

Sub advanceFirstDay()

    If advanced1Day = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    chart.Refresh()

    Dim gr As Graphics = chart.CreateGraphics
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 475, 115) 'x-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 60, 115, 60, 0)  'y-axis
    gr.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 55, 0, 65, 0) 'Tickmark
    gr.DrawString("10,000", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 0)
    gr.DrawString("Susceptible", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 90, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 1 Day", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 177, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Sick 2 Days", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 264, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Immune", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 351, 125)
    gr.DrawString("Population * 100", Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 200, 140)

    newImmune += twoDays
    newtwoDays = firstDay
    newSusceptible = susceptible - firstDay - newtwoDays - newImmune
    currentDay = CInt(0.0001735 * (newtwoDays * 100) * (newSusceptible * 100))
    newfirstDay = CInt(currentDay / 100)

    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 114 - newSusceptible, 30, newSusceptible) 'suscpetible
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 187, 114 - newfirstDay, 30, newfirstDay) 'sick one day
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 274, 114 - newtwoDays, 30, newtwoDays) 'sick two days
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 361, 114 - newImmune, 30, newImmune) 'sick two days

    advanced1Day = True

End Sub
```

End Class